# Debugging istio rate limiting handler

Tags: redis, handler, istio, rate-limiting, amazon-eks

I'm trying to apply rate limiting on some of our internal services (inside the mesh).

I used the example from the docs and generated redis rate limiting configurations that include  a (redis) handler, quota instance, quota spec, quota spec binding and rule to apply the handler.

This redis handler:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: redishandler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledAdapter: redisquota
  params:
    redisServerUrl: <REDIS>:6379
    connectionPoolSize: 10
    quotas:
    - name: requestcountquota.instance.istio-system
      maxAmount: 10
      validDuration: 100s
      rateLimitAlgorithm: FIXED_WINDOW
      overrides:
      - dimensions:
          destination: s1
        maxAmount: 1
      - dimensions:
          destination: s3
        maxAmount: 1
      - dimensions:
          destination: s2
        maxAmount: 1
```

The quota instance (I'm only interested in limiting by destination at the moment):

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: requestcountquota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: quota
  params:
    dimensions:
      destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.service.host | "unknown"
```

A quota spec, charging 1 per request if I understand correctly:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcountquota
```

A quota binding spec that all participating services pre-fetch. I also tried with `service: "*"` which also did nothing.

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: istio-system
  services:
  - name: s2
    namespace: default
  - name: s3
    namespace: default
  - name: s1
    namespace: default
    # - service: '*'  # Uncomment this to bind *all* services to request-count
```

A rule to apply the handler. Currently on all occasions (tried with matches but didn't change anything as well):

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: redishandler
    instances:
    - requestcountquota
```

The VirtualService definitions are pretty similar for all participants:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: s1
spec:
  hosts:
  - s1

  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: s1
```

The problem is nothing really happens and no rate limiting takes place. I tested with `curl` from pods inside the mesh. The redis instance is empty (no keys on db 0, which I assume is what the rate limiting would use) so I know it can't practically rate-limit anything.

The handler seems to be configured properly (how can I make sure?) because I had some errors in it which were reported in mixer (policy). There are still some errors but none which I associate to this problem or the configuration. The only line in which redis handler is mentioned is this:

```
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958041Z info    adapters    adapter closed all scheduled daemons and workers    {"adapter": "redishandler.istio-system"}
```

But its unclear if its a problem or not. I assume its not.

These are the rest of the lines from the reload once I deploy:

```
2019-12-17T13:44:22.601644Z info    Built new config.Snapshot: id='43'
2019-12-17T13:44:22.601866Z info    adapters    getting kubeconfig from: "" {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.601881Z warn    Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2019-12-17T13:44:22.602718Z info    adapters    Waiting for kubernetes cache sync...    {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.903844Z info    adapters    Cache sync successful.  {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.903878Z info    adapters    getting kubeconfig from: "" {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.903882Z warn    Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2019-12-17T13:44:22.904808Z info    Setting up event handlers
2019-12-17T13:44:22.904939Z info    Starting Secrets controller
2019-12-17T13:44:22.904991Z info    Waiting for informer caches to sync
2019-12-17T13:44:22.957893Z info    Cleaning up handler table, with config ID:42
2019-12-17T13:44:22.957924Z info    adapters    deleted remote controller   {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.957999Z info    adapters    adapter closed all scheduled daemons and workers    {"adapter": "prometheus.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958041Z info    adapters    adapter closed all scheduled daemons and workers    {"adapter": "redishandler.istio-system"}   
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958065Z info    adapters    shutting down daemon... {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958050Z info    adapters    shutting down daemon... {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958096Z info    adapters    shutting down daemon... {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:22.958182Z info    adapters    shutting down daemon... {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:44:23.958109Z info    adapters    adapter closed all scheduled daemons and workers    {"adapter": "kubernetesenv.istio-system"}
2019-12-17T13:55:21.042131Z info    transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2019-12-17T14:14:00.265722Z info    transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

I'm using the `demo` profile with `disablePolicyChecks: false` to enable rate limiting. This is on istio 1.4.0, deployed on EKS.

I also tried memquota (this is our staging environment) with low limits and nothing seems to work. I never got a 429 no matter how much I went over the rate limit configured.

I don't know how to debug this and see where the configuration is wrong causing it to do nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1, I also fail to get anything working with 1.4.2 & memquota on plain kubeadm clean cluster. I have spent a significant amount of time to debug to no avail. Would love to see some answers here too. I'll start a bounty.

Comment: I put the biggest bounty already. It expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too spent hours trying to decipher the documentation and get a sample working.

According to the documentation, they recommended that we enable policy checks:

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/

However when that did not work, I did an "istioctl profile dump", searched for policy, and tried several settings.

I used Helm install and passed the following and then was able to get the described behaviour:

--set global.disablePolicyChecks=false \
--set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true \ ===> this made it work, but it's not in the docs.

Comment: Thank you! This is too old and we dropped istio (partially because of this). I will give you the bounty though for pointing to some clue as to why this isn't working: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19139